# Vote split is completely broken on Meta

Tags: bug, voting, meta, status-completed

As the title says, it appears that vote splitting (1k+ rep feature) is broken on both questions and answers, CW and non-CW, on Meta only (SO works fine).

All I get is a popup message saying, "An error occurred during vote count fetch."

Edit: I can no longer view the close reasons either.

Answer (score 2):

We just switched from ASP.NET MVC 1 to 2.

This is an incredibly lame ASP.NET MVC 2 security "Feature" ...

[ASP.NET MVC 2.0 JsonRequestBehavior Global Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663221/asp-net-mvc-2-0-jsonrequestbehavior-global-setting)

Comment: It works now. Did you fix it, or roll back?

Comment: Geoff's edit says it all. Thanks!

Comment: I love how all these frameworks recently try to keep you from doing anything that even smells insecure, yet there is so many SQL injection bugs using these same frameworks..